# Android Camera returns image as landscape, getting it as Portrait?

Tags: android

In my android application I am using custom camera for capturing image when I am capturing the Image its showing landscape mode so,now im using rotate option  to change that to portrait so without using how can i capture my image in portrait mode please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

switch(orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: already I used this code for rotation .I want the image which I captured automatically has to come Portrait without using this rotate option